# NestJS DI - useFactory using request

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, nestjs, nestjs-config

In nestJS it is said that we can read properties from the request and insert into DI like this:

```javascript
@Module({
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [
            {
                provide: 'USER',
                scope: Scope.REQUEST,
                useFactory: (req:Request) => req["user"] ?? null,
            },
        ],
    exports: ['USER'],
})
```

Supposing a middleware reads the Bearer token, decode it and adds it to the current request as `req.user = <userINstance>` later I want to read it from it and adds to DI with token 'USER'.

In UserController I want to receive it as the following:

```
@Controller('/users')
export default class UserController {
  @Inject('USER') protected user: IUser;
  ...
}
```

But the factory wont work: it says

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

It seems the `req` is null, so `req["user"]` drops this exception. Tried to implement a similar simple example where tried to inject the `req.method` (post/get/etc) as string into DI. Same happened.

How to implement a factory like this? How to tell the nestJS that `req` is the current request? For example the following drops syntax error:

```
useFactory: (@Req() req:Request) => req["user"] ?? null,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from where did you import that `Request`?

Answer (score 0):

To inject the request into a factory, you need to add `inject: [REQUEST]` to the custom provider object.

Side note, `req.user` will probably be `undefined` as it won't have been populated yet, so it would be better to make a getter object that can be referenced on demand to get the value *later* rather than pulling the value off immediately

Comment: I read your similar suggestion here in stackoverflow on another question - I added the question there, now I must add also here: when I add `inject: [REQUEST],` - typescript compiler underlines the word `REQUEST` saying it is unknown. What is `REQUEST`? Where it came from?

Comment: `@nestjs/core`, [like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider)